# Custom Partitioner : N number of keys to N different files for word count

Tags: hadoop

Hi i am learning hadoop and i want a example on how to use custom partioner for word count problem. i want the set the reducers to 26 so that all the characters starts with "A" will go to  first reducer and all character "B" to second reducer and so on....

public class PersonPartitioner  extends Partitioner{

```
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable Val, int numOfReducer) {
    String line = key.toString();
    String [] splits = line.trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "").split("\\W+");
    for(String str:splits){

        if(null==str||str.trim().length()<1||""==str){
        }else{String ch = str.substring(0, 1);
            character.set(ch);
        }
    }




    return Math.abs(character.charAt(0).hashCode()*127)%numOfReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are doing word count the `Text key` should be a single word (hopefully that starts with a-z since you don't seem to care about numbers) not the entire line.

Second, if you know that this `Partitioner` will only be used in a case where there are 26 `Reducers` you can simply do this.

```
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable Val, int numOfReducer) {
   String word = key.toString();
   char char = word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
   return Charcter.getNumericValue(char) - Character.getNumericValue('a');
}
```